# How to generate semantic map which can visualize by visualisation_canvas?

Tags: knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed [KnowRob documentation](http://ias.in.tum.de/kb/wiki/index.php/Main_Page).

I want to generate semantic map OWL by adding objects one by one.

Where is the semantic map format doc which can visualize by visualisation_canvas?

And what's the simplest way to generate semantic map package to include my own semantic  map OWL?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43855/how-to-generate-semantic-map-which-can-visualize-by-visualisation_canvas?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-09-14

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2012-12-02**:
< simplest way to generate semantic map package to include my own semantic map OWL?> Do I have to create semantic map package to add my own semantic map?! I think it is not necessary cause just want to add owls but not to add new functionality for existing package ?! Do I have missing understand?

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-12-04**:
I use "register_ros_package(ias_semantic_map)." to import. So I need to create a package for semantic map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the simplest way is using the Semantic Map Editor:

http://ias.cs.tum.edu/kb/wiki/index.php/Mod_semantic_map

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) on 2012-09-23**:
Yes, it's described in the second answer to your question and described on the very same Wiki page as the interactive semantic map editor.

**Comment by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) on 2012-09-23**:
What do you mean with "by programming"? Of course, you could also just create owl-files manually or using a script... the map editor is just facilitate the map building...

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-09-25**:
I want to use programming language to send data as semantic map editor's input to generate my own semantic map OWL. Or is there any other convenient way to generate semantic map OWL? Thank you~

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Alternatively to the interactive semantic map editor GUI, there is also a ROS service in the same package that accepts a SemanticMap message and generates an OWL description. It's described on the same Wiki page Michi has mentioned.

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2012-09-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3